# Fetch env variables set by shibboleth in phusion passenger rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, shibboleth

In a rails4.2.0 app, with phusion passenger 5.0.2 under apache-2.2.22 (Debian GNU/Linux) I am not able to fetch environment variables set by mod_shibboleth (2.5.3-0switchaai1).

I used to write:
request.env["uid"]
in shibboleth-protected Locations, but now in request.env I find only "REMOTE_USER".

I am sure shibboleth-sp receives and set variables: I can see that both from logs and from a display script.

Variables set in /etc/apache2/envvars are received.

It looks I need to declare which variables pass from apache2 to phusion-passenger, but docs say the opposite (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#env_vars_passenger_apps).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out it was a issue on phusion-passenger: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1446

It was fixed on passenger-5.0.6.

Francesco